# CodeIgniter: Accessing view variables from helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am extending form_helper that will populate data from an array in view.

E.g:

```
//Controller - user_controller.php
User_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function edit(){
        $data['record'] = array('username'=>'robert','email'=>'simplerobert@google.com');
        $this->load->view('edit',$data);
    }
}


//View - edit.php
<?= $record['username']; ?> >> 'robert'
<?= simple_input('halo'); ?>

//Helper - MY_form_helper.php
function simple_input($name){
    var_dump($record); >> Undefined variable: record
    return "<input type='text'/>";
}
```

I thought helper should load up the variables from view. Didn't really understand how it works. How can I access the view variables from helper?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the variable in the function:

```
//...

//View - edit.php
<?= $record['username']; ?> >> 'robert'
<?= simple_input('halo', $record); ?>


//Helper - MY_form_helper.php
function simple_input($name, $record){
    var_dump($record);
    return "<input type='text'/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

helper is function, so you need to pass the var into the function to use it.
(tttony wrote about this.)

I think you'd better make another view.
in that case you don't need to pass the vars.

```
//View - edit.php
<?= $record['username']; ?> >> 'robert'
<?= $this->load->view('simple_input'); ?>

//View simple_input.php
var_dump($record);
echo "<input type='text'/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

helper is function, so you need to pass the var into the function to use it. (tttony wrote about this.)
I think you'd better make another view. in that case you don't need to pass the vars.

```
//View - edit.php
<?= $record['username']; ?> >> 'robert'
<?= $this->load->view('simple_input'); ?>

//View simple_input.php
var_dump($record);
echo "<input type='text'/>";
```